# Laravel doesnt show validation messages correctly

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in my controller i have

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "list_img" => "required",
        "ge_title" => "required|max:255"
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

if validation fails i got messages -

validation.required

validation.required .....

instead of

ge_title is required

list_img is required

p.s. I have 3 languages on my site and i dont have validation.php file in resources/lang (if it matters)

Comment: yes, it's language file might be missing. check whether you had appropriate `validation.php` in each language directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the third argument the error messages:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "list_img" => "required",
        "ge_title" => "required|max:255"
    ], [
        "list_img.required" => "List img is required",
        "ge_title.required" => trans('errors.required'), //if you have multilang. then use trans function
        "ge_title.max" => trans('errors.max_title')
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: @heavymetal91 If it helps you should accept the answer.

Comment: I did it several times) dont know why nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

It is not

> $request->query->all()

instead of

> $request->all()

for post or something like this ?

Comment: thanks for reply. the code bellow your comment works